# Why do I need two loops for bubble sort?

Tags: python, bubble-sort

Im a beginner in programming and my question would be:
Why do I need 2 "for loops" for this to work?
Thanks for any answers in advance ^^

```
# Bubble sort

a = [2092, 8966, 564331, 989]
laenge = len(a)

for i in range(1,laenge):
    for j in range(0,laenge-i):
        if a[j] > a[j+1]:
            tempdata = a[j]
            a[j] = a[j+1]
            a[j+1] = tempdata
        
print (a)

print (" Surprise monkey")
```

Comment: Because that's how the bubble sort algorithm works, you have to perform multiple passes over the list.  You might want to read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: Each internal loop completion makes the next largest element "float up" to its place (hence the algorithm name). You need to repeat it for each element.

Comment: Because it's a really inefficient way to sort things.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do in a single loop but you still need two control variables to manage the multiple passes through the data.  Each pass can be optimized by shortening the range by 1 given that the last position will get its appropriate element in the sorted order.  The whole loop can be stopped as soon as one pass makes no swaps.

Basic form:

```
a = [2092, 8966, 564331, 989]

i,j = 1,len(a)-1
while j:
    if i>j: i,j = 1,j-1           # new pass 
    if a[i-1]>a[i]:
        a[i-1],a[i] = a[i],a[i-1] # preform swap
    i += 1                        # next swap index

print(a)
[989, 2092, 8966, 564331]
```

With swap detection optimizations:

```
a = [2092, 8966, 564331, 989]
    
last    = len(a)  # sorted positions from last to 1st
i       = last+1  # current swapping index
swapped = True    # swap detection
while last:
    if i>last:    # pass complete, reset indexes
        if not swapped: break # done if no swaps made
        last -= 1             # last is sorted
        i,swapped = 1,False   # start new pass
    if a[i-1]>a[i]:
        a[i-1],a[i] = a[i],a[i-1] # preform swap
        swapped = True
    i += 1                    # next swap index
    
print(a)
[989, 2092, 8966, 564331]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way bubble sort works is that after every time you pass through the list, it guarantees that the next largest element will be pushed to the end of the list (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JP5KkzdUEYI).

So to pass through the list once we use a loop (inner loop) that swaps every pair of elements if they are out of order. After performing this once the last element is sorted, twice the last two elements are sorted, etc. So to completely sort the list we need to loop through the data n times where n is the number of elements (outer loop).

This nested loop is why bubble sort is O(n^2) and is not a preferred sorting algorithm

```
a = [2092, 8966, 564331, 989] 
laenge = len(a)

for i in range(1,laenge): # run inner loop n times to sort all elements
    for j in range(0,laenge-i): # completing this loop will sort the last unsorted element
        if a[j] > a[j+1]:
            tempdata = a[j]
            a[j] = a[j+1]
            a[j+1] = tempdata
```